# Refresh the microsoft teams chat with bot embedded code

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I have created a bot using bot composer and I have generated bot embed URL. I have accessed the same URL in browser and it got opened successfully in Microsoft teams

Now when I have updated the bot and published in azure, I am not finding an option to refresh this same in Microsoft teams
Is there any way to refresh the session and start the chat again with new modified bot????

Answer (score 0):

when you update the bot and publish it in azure, the bot ID and user Id will not change so, the chat id will be remains same in the backend and you can't refresh the chat window in teams. This is by design.

Comment: @Praneeth Does that help clarify? Let me know if you have additional questions.